# Tensorflow - Making tensor untrainable

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I create a tensor using `tf.Variable`, I can decide whether the tensor will be trainable or not. However how can I set tensor B to be untrainable if I define it in the following way:

```
A=tf.placeholder(tf.int32,shape=[None,100])

B=tf.zeros_like(A)
```

Comment: This way, the B tensor is already not trainable. If you want B to be trainable, and initialized with zeros, use e.g. `tf.Variable(tf.zeros_like(A))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A=tf.placeholder(tf.int32,shape=[None,100])`
A is a placeholder, not a Variable. A placeholder is *not* trainable.

If you create a variable and set the attribute `trainable` to `False`

```
x = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
```

your variable wont be trainable.

If you create a new variable, with `tf.zeros_like(x)`, this new variable will have the same attributes of `x`.

```
y = tf.zeros_like(x)
```

You can verify that the 2 variables are not trainable, looking into the `GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` collection, using the convenience function `tf.trainable_variables`.

Here's the sample code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
assert [] == tf.trainable_variables()
y = tf.zeros_like(x)
assert [] == tf.trainable_variables()
```

So, if you want to create a new variable with the same shape and type of a placeholder, and you want to make it trainable, you have to manually define it without using convenience function that will copy even the `trainable` (always `False` for a placeholder) attribute.